# SMOTE for multiclass classification

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, multi-class

I have a dataset in which the target variable has three classes. The approx distribution is as follows:

- "-1" - 4%
- "0" - 90%
- "1" - 6%

I did not find any package in R which can run smote for multilabel classification( Please tell me if there is). So i compromised and did the following

- Forget about class "-1", apply SMOTE on classes 1 and 0
- Next, forget about class 0, apply SMOTE on classes 1 and -1
- Next, forget about class 1, apply SMOTE on classes 0 and -1

Is that the right way to proceed?

Also there is an existing paper on how to do SMOTE for mutliclass classification [here](http://nparc.cisti-icist.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/eng/view/fulltext/?id=e8c7556d-9f94-466f-a1e5-72cdf9b9513f) . It's called SCUT.

Is there an application of this SCUT algorithm in any R or python package?

Answer (score 4):

I would agree with running multiple SMOTE passes across the dataset, but with a slightly different view than already expressed. If you merely run SMOTE for each minority class against the predominant class, you're going to be generating sample that models the *difference between each minority class and the predominant class* rather than sample that models the class as accurately as possible.

We can fix this (as much as is possible in this case) by SMOTE oversampling each minority class against *all data not in that class.* For example, the first SMOTE run may be the "1" class against the union of the "-1" and "0" classes and the second might be the "-1" class against the union of the "1" and "0" classes.

Conceptually, this is simply minority oversampling of "1" and "not 1" and the same with "-1".

Alternatively, given enough available sample otherwise, another option would be to massively *undersample* the "0" class to balance the class distributions.

Comment: Also undersample would not be a good idea in my dataset

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your question, you are trying to balance "-1" class and "1", but they are seemed to be almost equally. So, it would be more right to 1)apply SMOTE on classes -1 and 0, then 2) apply SMOTE on classes 0 and 1. Then you may get all classes balanced.